# Property delegation by Map for open hierarchies

Tags: kotlin, delegates, immutability

Consider I have a base of an open hierarchy where all the properties are [delegated](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#storing-properties-in-a-map) to a single map:

```
interface JsonExternalizable {
    fun serialize(): MutableMap<String, JsonNode>
}

abstract class AbstractJsonExternalizable protected constructor(private val map: Map<String, Any?>) : JsonExternalizable {
    override fun serialize(): MutableMap<String, JsonNode> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now a sample **immutable** implementation (I want to have an additional secondary constructor where the list of arguments would "mirror" the type's corresponding properties):

```
open class Bean1 protected constructor(map: Map<String, Any?>) : AbstractJsonExternalizable(map) {
    constructor(property1: String,
                property2: Int,
                property3: Boolean) : this(mapOf(Bean1::property1 to property1,
                                                 Bean1::property2 to property2,
                                                 Bean1::property3 to property3).mapKeys { it.key.name })

    val property1: String by map
    val property2: Int by map
    val property3: Boolean by map
}
```

Things get worse for more "distant" descendants, as I have to list **every** supertype property (along with the own properties) in the secondary constructor:

```
class Bean3 private constructor(map: Map<String, Any?>) : Bean1(map) {
    val propertyX: Array<Byte> by map

    constructor(property1: String,
                property2: Int,
                property3: Boolean,
                propertyX: Array<Byte>) : this(mapOf(Bean3::property1 to property1,
                                                     Bean3::property2 to property2,
                                                     Bean3::property3 to property3,
                                                     Bean3::propertyX to propertyX).mapKeys { it.key.name })
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to express the same idea, with less boilerplate code?